# ffmpeg resulting in no audio and unplayble video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to get ffmpeg to work as expected however I am having all kinds of trouble getting it to work.

I need to output a webm and h264 for web play.  However, the command I am using, while it used to work a few years ago, does not work at all now.

Both my webm and h264 do not have audio, and neither will play in any browser.

My command for webm is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$KMVAR_File" -c:v libvpx -crf 24 -b:v 1000k -vf scale=720:-2 -c:a libvorbis "$KMVAR_webmPath"
```

and my command for mp4 is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$KMVAR_File" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -crf 32 -b:v 1M -minrate 1M -maxrate 1M -bufsize 2M -vf scale=720:-2 -c:a aac -strict experimental -movflags +faststart "$KMVAR_mp4Path"
```

Comment: which ffmpeg version are you using ?

Comment: 4.3 I have realized it has something to do with the audio tracks I think...the source video has 16 audio tracks, but I only need 2, not sure how to fix that

Comment: Oh, that's a pain : do you know which you want ? Or do you want to downmix multiple tracks (say 6 tracks from a 5.1 stream) into stereo ?)

Comment: @smwhr the video is in stereo on channels 1 and 2, I dont need 3-16 i am trying `-ac 2` right now to see if that works

Comment: Show the complete log for each command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When playing with multiple audio, downmixing or extracting, there's no "one size fit all" solution with ffmpeg.

Look at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation as it provides multiple possible solution to your problem.

(I usually go with the `pan` filter : not the easiest to use, but more powerful than the `map_channel` approach)